# Можно ли ограничить длину TextView?

Tags: android, java

Привет. Такой вопрос. У TextView есть поле maxLength, но во-первых оно считает количество символов, во-вторых просто обрубает текст. А надо фиксировать именно длину внешнего представления (т.к. очевидно wwwwww и iiiiii будут разной длины, хотя обе из 6 символов), и на конце оставлять троеточие (пример: "Вася беж..."). Можно ли это сделать стандартными средствами виджета?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Свойство ellipsize у `TextView` обрезает текст.

Чтобы обрезать в конце, надо юзать  `ellipsize="end"`

Comment: @Suvitruf похоже, что так, но что-то тут все-равно не чисто. Со свойствами

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        ...
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:linksClickable="false"
        android:maxLines="1" />

никаких изменений не заметил, по прежнему просто обрубает строку, а не на полуслове http://data3.floomby.com/files/share/1_10_2014/12/wYkUArpkAEupK68iHv2ZQ.jpg

Comment: попробуйте   android:singleLine="true" добавить

Comment: @Suvitruf да, спасибо большое, так сработало.